# Checked my query several times but still SQL Errors: Incorrect syntax near '.'.. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Tags: sql, syntax

I have already looked at multiples answers and fix some issues in my query but I can't find where is my mistake in the following syntax. It is not a difficult query I guess but I need help on this one.

```
SELECT
A.SubscriberKey as ContactKey,
F.JobID as [Code Email],
A.EventDate as [Date Envoi],
B.EventDate as [Date Ouverture],
(CASE
    WHEN B.EventDate is not null THEN 'True' ELSE 'False'
END) AS B.Ouverture,
C.EventDate as [Date Clic],
(CASE
    WHEN C.EventDate is not null THEN 'True' ELSE 'False'
END) AS C.Clic,
D.EventDate as [Date Bounce],
(CASE
    WHEN D.EventDate is not null THEN 'True' ELSE 'False'
END) AS D.Bounce,
E.EventDate as [Date désabonnement],
(CASE
    WHEN E.EventDate is not null THEN 'True' ELSE 'False'
END) AS E.Désabonnement,
F.EmailName as [Nom Email]
FROM _Job F
INNER JOIN _Sent A ON A.JobID = F.JobID
INNER JOIN _Open B ON B.JobID = F.JobID
INNER JOIN _Click C ON C.JobID = F.JobID
INNER JOIN _Bounce D ON D.JobID = F.JobID
INNER JOIN _Unsubscribe E ON E.JobID = F.JobID
```

I wish I could find the error by myself because it seems to be linked with coma or '' but I can't find it...

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server? Otherwise those dreaded square brackets `[...]` are invalid SQL

Comment: try what I do in these situations: keep removing small chunks of the query until the problem goes away - the last removed chunk has the problem.

Comment: `END) AS B.Ouverture,`

Comment: @jarlh post your comment as an answer (or I will!)

Comment: I can't understand when people write big SQL statements without executing them during the process. I still do it, after decades.

Comment: @jarlh maybe OP is writing it in a dev tool. Whatever the case, the brains trust that thought `"you have a problem near '.'"` would be useful without a line/position info were mistaken.

Comment: I used https://developer.mimer.com/services/sql-validator-99/ to spot the syntax errors. (Had to replace [ and ] with " first.)

Answer (score 2):

Column aliases can't be qualified:

Change `END) AS B.Ouverture,` to `END) AS B_Ouverture,`, etc.

In ANSI SQL, identifiers can't start with underscore (`_`):

Change `_Job`  to `[_Job]`, if needed.